# "rev" command: I want to reverse only $string but it reverses everything before $string too

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, scripting

```
read -p "Input a sentence: " mystring
string=("$mystring" | rev)
echo "The sentence reversed character by character is: " $string
```

I want to reverse only $string but it reverses everything before $string to. Can someone help me pls?

Comment: You are trying to run `$mystring` as a command. Try `$(echo $mystring | rev)` for better results. It would also help to give a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 3):

You need to feed the string as standard input to `rev`, either using a herestring or heredoc or by piping the output of `printf` and then collect the output of `rev` using *command substitution*.

```
IFS= read -rep 'Input a sentence: ' mystring

string=$(
  rev <<< "$mystring"
)
# or:
string=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$mystring" | rev
)

printf '%s\n' "The sentence reversed character by character is: $string"
```

Note that `rev` is not a standard command (though is pretty common). Had you used `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could have done the reversing internally (and also be able to let the user enter anything):

```
mystring=
vared -p 'Input a sentence: ' mystring
string=${(j[])${(s[]Oa)mystring}}
print -r The sentence reversed character by character is: $string
```

(note that since `zsh`'s `vared`, as opposed to `bash`'s `read -e` allows the user to include newline characters (and any character, even NUL) in the contents of the `var` that is `ed`ited, using `rev` to reverse it would not work as `rev` works on one line at a time).

In `bash`, remember:

- parameter expansions must be quoted. In your `echo` line, you had quoted parts that didn't need quoted, and omitted the quotes in the only place where they were needed.
- To read a line, it's [`IFS= read -r line`](/q/209123). `read line` does something completely different.
- [`echo` can't be used to output arbitrary data. Use `printf` instead](/q/65803).